# Add a number of day in a localdate column

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I use spring data jpa

I search to do something like

```
@Query("update FROM sample s set s.availableForTest=true WHERE (s.buildDate + s.delay) <= date and availableForTest=false")
public void updateToAvailabilityForTest(@Param("date") LocalDate date);
```

Delay is number of day to add

Seem like not possible with JPQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible in JPQL. Not even in plain SQL this is possible in at least SQL Server and MySQL. There are dedicated functions for this:

SQL Server - [DATEADD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

MySQL - [DATE_ADD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

I think it is possible though in Oracle.

So the easiest way is to do a native query using this date adding functions.

If you would like to stay in the JPQL world and have JPA 2.1 available, then they introduced there the [`FUNCTION`](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/j_func.htm) function in JPQL which you can use to call database functions.

Note that:

> `FUNCTION` is database specific – it does not translate the function
>   call in any way to support different databases as other JPQL functions
>   do.

In your case and using SQL Server this would look like:

```
update FROM sample s set s.availableForTest=true WHERE FUNCTION('DATEADD', 'day' , s.delay, s.buildDate) <= :date and availableForTest=false
```

Although i havent tested id.